# Disable train accuracy testing after each epoch

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

When I use `tf.keras.Model.fit()`, I get train accuracy testing after every epoch:

```
Epoch 1/50
420/420 - 3s - loss: 0.1289 - accuracy: 0.9633 - lr: 0.0010
```

I use `CUDA`, so the learning process itself is fast, but accuracy testing after each epoch greatly slow down the training process.
Even more when I do the hyperparameters tuning.

So, how can I disable it?

Comment: Just do not add an accuracy metrics when calling model.compile, or are you talking about the validation phase?

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy no, I'm talking about train accuracy. Thanks. I didn't think it would be so easy.

Comment: Well the thing is that computing validation accuracy should not be a considerable slowdown

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy do you mean training accuracy? Because I mean only it :)

Comment: No, you said "accuracy testing after each epoch" and that sounds like validation metrics. Computing training accuracy is also very fast.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy I also said "I get train accuracy testing after every epoch" in the very first sentence and in the title, and I meant it. :) But now I see that disabling training accuracy does not give much performance gain. Anyway, thanks!